# android list checkbox

Tags: android, list, checkbox, android-cursoradapter

This Android view recycling thing is pretty insane, I've spent all day trying to get a workaround.

This is my code and which is not working

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context currentContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private boolean[] rows;

    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        currentContext = context;
        mCursor = c;
        populateRows();
    }

    private void populateRows() {
        rows = new boolean[mCursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            rows[i] = false;
            i++;            
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        // convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.darkred);
        if (v != null) {
            //getting checkbox
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            if(rows[position]){
                rows[position] = false;
            }else{
                rows[position] = true;
            }
            cb.setChecked(rows[position]);

        }

        return super.getView(position, v, parent);
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific. What are you trying to do? What isn't working? How isn't it working? The more information you provide, the better help you'll get.

Comment: im returning cursor from db and this checked state of a checkbox isnt related to any db column its only suposed to visualise to user which of these rows are selected. Later i m adding selected values to another table in db and that part is working i just cant make this selcting of checkboxes to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Many things wrong here:

- Don't change state in getView. I refer to flipping rows[position]. getView may be called many times to draw the same list row. As a side note you can flip by using a = !a;
- Set the checked state out of the if on v != null. If you recycle a view, you still need to initialize it's UI, as it may be set with state of a different data row.
- If the view is not null, and you reuse it, return it
- If the view is null, you need to create new instances, for example by inflating layout

Comment: ok thanks i get your point. So where should i change state maybe in list activity in onListItemClick method ? that wont work either